# Are all pairs of events timelike related which were passed by a photon orbiting in a photon sphere?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime

If two (distinct) events both belong to the same [photon sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere), and if a photon had been passing both these events (in other words: if these two events are connected by a [null (lightlike) curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Curves) which completely belongs to the photon sphere under consideration)
are these two events also connected by a [chronological (timelike) curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure#Curves) (which does not necessarily completely belong to the photon sphere) ?

Certain pairs of such events quite obviously have this chronological (timelike) relation, namely:
["*It is possible to imagine a photon that begins at the back of your head, orbiting the black hole, only then to be intercepted by your eyes, allowing you to see the back of your head.*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere);
but I like to know whether this applies to all event pairs specified above.

Comment: Do you consider the region below the event horizon to be in scope of your photon sphere?

Comment: @JMLCarter: "_Do you consider the region below the event horizon to be in scope of your photon sphere?_" -- Certainly not for the purpose of my question above (which is pretty much grounded on the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere); and I wouldn't know by which stretch of terminology or imagination otherwise, either.

Comment: Assume that causality isn't broken or novel in the photon sphere. In your example (assuming the back and front of your head are the same point) the two events have a timelike relation, but it is clear that there was lightlike motion around the photon sphere in between the events. One wouldn't observer these events and derive a low measurement of c, for example. 
Have you met these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_diagram ?

Comment: @JMLCarter: "_In your example [...] the two events have a timelike relation, but it is clear that there was lightlike motion around the photon sphere in between the events._" -- Well, it seems a fair example, given some "sensible assumptions". However, my question is about "the general case". "_One wouldn't [...] derive a low measurement of c_" -- Correct. Here's a hint about the immediate motivation for my question: To explore viability or limitations of 't Hooft's proposal concerning "spatial distance" (from 1979) which I recently found mentioned in https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1768 (p. 5).

Comment: I understand a lightlike relation is a special case of timelike relation. If event one lies on the Minkowski diagram origin, then if event 2 is reachable at the speed of light or less, then the relation is timelike. if event 2 is only reachable at c, then it is a lightlike relation.
Examples of events causally connected by photons in free space are lightlike and therefore must also be at the limit of being timelike.
I doubt I'll be much help with quantum gravity theories.